# SQL add an extra column from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked around the web but SQL is new to me so the correct syntax escapes me because of all the fancy joins etc. How would I be able to achieve the following:

```
SELECT 
event.Id, 
event.Name, 
event.Date,
event.Size,  
event.Email,  
verificationdata.Value,

/*I want the below value column duplicated, using data from the next comment*/
verificationdata.Value

FROM event
INNER JOIN verification on event.Id = verification.EventId
INNER JOIN verificationdata on verificationdata.vId = verification.Id
WHERE event.Id > 00001
AND 
(verificationdata.Field = 'Grievances'OR verificationdata.Field = 'ERROR')

/*Pulling THIS data into the duplicated column*/
WHERE verificationdata.Field = 'VideoDurationPTS_0'



Id | Name | Date   | Size | Email     | verificationdata.Value  | verificationdata.Value                                   
01 | Dave | 01-Jan | 2000 | d@d.com   | A                       | B                            
02 | Bob  | 02-Jan | 3000 | b@b.com   | A                       | B
```

A =(Value when verificationdata.Field = Grievances)
B =(Value when verificationdata.Field = Duration)
Any help would be super!

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
event.Id, 
event.Name, 
event.Date,
event.Size,  
event.Email,  
MAX(CASE WHEN verification.Field IN ('Grievances') THEN 'A' END) as val1,
MAX(CASE WHEN verification.Field IN ('VideoDurationPTS_0') THEN 'B' END) as 
val2
FROM event
INNER JOIN verification on event.Id = verification.EventId
INNER JOIN verificationdata on verificationdata.vId = verification.Id
WHERE event.Id > 00001
AND 
(verificationdata.Field in( 'Grievances','ERROR','VideoDurationPTS_0')
group by event.Id, event.Name, event.Date, event.Size,  event.Email
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax
near 'WHERE verificationdata.Field = 'VideoDurationPTS_0' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 15

Comment: @Dave, modified the answer, you can check now

Comment: Edited version doesn't error out but returns zero rows. Removing the last AND returns a column filled with the string 'VideoDurationPTS_0' instead of the values from verificationdata.Value when verificationdata.Field = 'VideoDurationPTS_0'

Comment: can you please provide your expected output in question @Dave

Comment: I've updated the question to provide a rough example of expected output!

Comment: @Dave, modified the answer, you can check now

Comment: There was a missing ) at the end of the second to last row but this worked. Thank you for your persistence!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Name, e.Date, e.Size, e.Email,  
       MAX(CASE WHEN vd.Field IN ('Grievances', 'ERROR') THEN vd.Value END) as field,
       MAX(CASE WHEN vd.Field IN ('VideoDurationPTS_0') THEN vd.Value END) as VideoDurationPTS_0
FROM event e INNER JOIN
     verification v
     ON e.Id = v.EventId INNER JOIN
     verificationdata vd
     ON vd.vId = v.Id
WHERE e.Id > 00001 AND
      vd.Field IN ('Grievances', 'ERROR', 'VideoDurationPTS_0')
GROUP BY e.Id, e.Name, e.Date, e.Size, e.Email;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'vd.Field' in 'field list'

Comment: @Dave Debugging is part of programmer's job.  The error message is very clear.  We don't know the exact structure of your table because it's not given.  So debug the code.  You have the table structure.  Does your table `verificationdata` contains a column called `Field`???  If not then that's your problem.  The solution is to replace `Field` with the real column name.

Comment: For sure, however this solution is wildly different to my initial attempt, in contrast to  fa06's solution. I reiterate, SQL is new to me, I can only debug what I can understand. verificationdata contains two columns, Field and Value, so I'm unsure where this code fell down.